# enviar mismas nombres en un form

Tags: php, html, formularios

Hola lo que quisiera saber es si se pueden enviar input con el mismo nombre mediante un form a otra pagina   tengo este html

```
<form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">

 <p>Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario"></p>
 <p>Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario"></p>
 <p>Contraseña: <input type="password" name="pass"></p>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar datos"></p>

 </form>
```

al enviarlos la persona escribira dos usuarios diferentes pero estos tienen el mismo nombre  al enviarlos a la pagina solo recibe un usuario, se podria colocarles el mismo nombre y que se envien los dos o eso no se puede?

Comment: No se puede, ponles otros nombres como usuario1 y usuario2.

Answer (score 0):

Empezando, no puedes utilizar dos veces la misma variable puesto a que única y exclusivamente te agarrará la primera.. entonces ¿cuál es la recomendación? crea una función en javascript que te genere un input nuevo cada vez que hagas clic en X botón el cual va tener por nombre un vector.. es decir

name="usuario[]" y a la hora de obtener la información en el modelo lo único que debes hacer es recorrerlo con un FOR.

for($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++)
echo (usuario[$i]);

Y wuala.. tendrás tus datos.

Yo por ejemplo.. para agregar grupos en mi BD hice lo siguiente

```html
<form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/Agregar_grupos/registrar_grupo" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>Agregar un nueva Clasificación</legend>
    <label for="example-month-input" class="col-12 col-form-label">Clasificación:</label>
    <input name="grupo[]" type="text" class="form-control w-50" required>
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus btn btn-success" id="add"></i>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" class ="btn btn-success w-50 mt-3 " value="Aceptar" class="add" id="add" />
</form>
```

Eso como parte del HTMl..

Y por parte del Javascript

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
    var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
    var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div  class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
    var fName = $("<br> <input    name=\"grupo[]\" type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname form-control w-50\" required/>");

    var removeButton = $("<i class=\"mdi mdi-delete btn btn-danger ml-1\"></i>");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
$("#preview").click(function() {
    $("#yourform").remove();
    var fieldSet = $("<fieldset id=\"yourform\"><legend>Your Form</legend></fieldset>");
    $("#buildyourform div").each(function() {
        var id = "input" + $(this).attr("id").replace("field","");
        var label = $("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + $(this).find("input.fieldname").first().val() + "</label>");
        var input;
        switch ($(this).find("select.fieldtype").first().val()) {
            case "checkbox":
                input = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" />");
                break;
            case "textbox":
                input = $("<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" />");
                break;
            case "textarea":
                input = $("<textarea id=\"" + id + "\" name=\"" + id + "\" ></textarea>");
                break;    
        }
        fieldSet.append(label);
        fieldSet.append(input);
    });
    $("body").append(fieldSet);
});
```

Suerte! espero que te funcione, actualmente ese código funciona al 100% en mi proyecto. OJO, el JS es para cuando le des CLIC al botón de AÑADIR te creará un nuevo INPUT con el mismo nombre (usuario[]). Recuerda, es importante que sea un vector.